# Movie not loaded when i load flash on sharepoint 2010

Tags: flash, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

When I upload flash content on my Sharepoint 2010 page i get a white blank space, when i right click i see "movie not load". I tried using swfobject but still no luck, tried using just a simple falsh file but still no luck. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Can you show us some code on how you are trying to publish those movies?

Comment: Sorry I couldnt show the code at the time, but all is working fine now, seems i had to enable a setting to allow the flash to playback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you storing the files of the movies you are truying to load?

On SharePoint or outside, if outside you might have to set a cross domain policy:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html

Comment: I had to configure the server to allow such extensions, all is well now, Thanks